# Trigger Segue - When UITableView Finishes Reloading Itself

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here is how my StoryBoard looks like:

`UINavigationController -> UIViewController -> UITableViewController`

I want the UIViewController to act as a `waiting screen` while the `UITableViewController` fetches the data asynchronously from the server. Once the `UITableViewController` has finished fetching data, Only then I want to perform a segue to the `UITableViewController` from `UIViewController`

In my `UIViewController` I have setup basic KVO:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tableView = MyUITableViewController()
    tableView.viewDidLoad() //How to initiate ViewController?
    ...
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "tableReady:", name: "TableReady", object: nil)
}

  func tableReady(notification: NSNotification) {
    if notification.name == "tableReady"{
        print("TableViewReady")
        //perform segue here
    }
 }
```

In UITableView I'm posting Notification when tableView has fetched data and is ready

```
private var posts = [Post]() {
    didSet {
        if posts.count == self.postsLimit{
            print("reloading data")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("tableReady", object: self)
            })

        }
    }
}
```

This does not work. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Try to add a print statement before NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver... and one before NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName... If the data is loaded before viewDidLoad is called your first ViewConrtoller won't be notificated.

Answer (score 0):

Decouple the data fetching from the UITableViewController, and move that functionality into a delegate class. Then, from the `UIViewController`, tell the delegate to fetch data and then trigger the `UIViewController`'s segue. When the table reloads, it looks to the delegate for the data.